# How to reset the context to the original rectangle after clipping it for drawing?

Tags: iphone

I try to draw a sequence of pattern images (different repeated patterns in one view).

So what I did is this, in a loop:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// clip to the drawing rectangle to draw the pattern for this portion of the view
CGContextClipToRect(context, drawingRect);

// the first call here works fine... but for the next nothing will be drawn
CGContextDrawTiledImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 2, 31), [img CGImage]);
```

I think that after I've clipped the context to draw the pattern in the specific rectangle, I cut out a snippet from the big canvas and the next time, my canvas is gone. can't cut out another snippet. So I must reset that clipping somehow in order to be able to draw another pattern again somewhere else?

Edit: In the documentation I found this:

> CGContextClip: "... Therefore, to
>   re-enlarge the paintable area by
>   restoring the clipping path to a prior
>   state, you must save the graphics
>   state before you clip and restore the
>   graphics state after you’ve completed
>   any clipped drawing. ..."

Well then, how to store the graphics state before clipping and how to restore it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The functions you are looking for are:

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);
```

and

```
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```